# Data-active-index not updating in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a js file to update the index based on the cursor's position on the items of a menu This is the code i used:

```
const menu = document.getElementById("menu");
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item"))
  .forEach((item, index) => {
    item.onmouseover = () => {
      menu.dataset.activeIndex = index;
    }
  });
```

The index updating is supposed to move a background image using css

```
#menu[data-active-index="0"] > #menu-background-pattern {
    background-position: 0% -25%;
  }

  #menu[data-active-index="1"] > #menu-background-pattern {
    background-position: 0% -50%;
  }

  #menu[data-active-index="2"] > #menu-background-pattern {
    background-position: 0% -75%;
  }

  #menu[data-active-index="3"] > #menu-background-pattern {
    background-position: 0% -100%;
  }
```

The Background image is not moving While The background image should have moved
Here is the html

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="menu-items">
      <div class="menu-item">Home</div>
      <div class="menu-item">Shop</div>
      <div class="menu-item">About</div>
      <div class="menu-item">Contact Us</div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-background-pattern"></div>
    <div id="menu-background-image"></div>
  </div>
  <script></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
```

Comment: Please include the HTML. (and css). Perhaps #menu-background-pattern is not a direct child of #menu.

Comment: Your code, as provided, works fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/z7d6avft/1/   Please provide a *complete* snippet (that includes your HTML) that *demonstrates* the issue.  See [mcve].

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks For The Response I have attached the Html. I also have Tried the code on jsfddle and it works there but not on my vercel instance

Comment: Something to try: add `console.log(Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item")).length)` if this is zero (0) then your code is running too soon - move your code as far to the end as your framework hosts allows - specifically after the menu-item elements have been created - altternatively, wrap your code in a DOMContentLoaded event handler ([example](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ready))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with the JavaScript code you wrote (Well, you didn't really write it, this code is from a codepen by Hyperplexed.)

1. The code is running too early.
   -If the code is running too early, then there are no elements for the code to apply the `onmouseover` event. (Credit to @freedomn-m)
2. The `.forEach()` method does not loop over properties, it loops over indices.

**How to fix it**

Let's fix the first issue first. Make a method that takes in a function and runs it whenever the document is ready.

```
function ready(fn) {
    if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
        fn();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
    }
}
```

Now we wrap the original JS code in a function and run it when it's ready

```
function menuListener () {
    const menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item"))
        .forEach((item, index) => {
            item.onmouseover = () => {
                menu.dataset.activeIndex = index;
        }
    });
}
function ready(fn) {
    if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
        fn();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
    }
    // This function was taken from https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ready (Found through @freedomn-m's comment)
}
ready(menuListener)
```

Next, we change the way we loop over the elements

```
function menuListener () {
    const menuItems = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item"))
    const menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    for (let i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
        menuItems[i].onmouseover = () => {
            menu.dataset.activeIndex = i
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, we completely changed the way we loop over the elements. (I also added the menuItems constant for extra readability)

Comment: Thanks for your help and this is hyperplexed's code and he has tutorial on how to create this effect on his YouTube channel I am trying to learn CSS and JavaScript and thought it would be good to see them working together in a deployment

Comment: You're welcome! This is a very good habit. Try to experiment with code you found online and see what changes what, and understand how it works. In the industry, you will be reading more code than writing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i got the fix. the problem was due to using class or id in html. for modifying, a div named using class we should use '.' or if the div is named using id we should use '#'